# How to change in bootstrap navbar height?

Tags: navbar

I want to change height of navbar in bootstrap. My code:

```
         <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="navbar-brand">MyDatoo</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I want to change this navbar height:
[image]

Comment: you can use css for that

Comment: I know, but how change in bootstrap css height?

Comment: you can overide bootstrap css. i will give answer follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.navbar {
    height: 100px !important; /*i assume your navbar size 100px*/
}
```

if you dealing with mobile

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .navbar {
    height: 100px !important; 
   }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .navbar {
    height: 120px !important; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: This code add this height after navbar, don't resizing.

Comment: you can resize height accordingly.when use jquery for resizing you can set that height as !important

Comment: But this navbar has smart phones version, in smart phones version HTML code is same, but height is different.

Comment: you can use media query in css for that

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp. you can change height of nav bar accordingly for each screen size

Comment: I know it, but how change height for my variant which is in my photo?

Comment: your are not mention all those things in your question..I dont know what your mind..please mention all the details of the problem in question.

Comment: this is extract answer for your question I think..you must change your question accordingly.

Comment: I only want to find place in bootstrap css, where i can change height of navbar.

Comment: you can use inspect element in browser to check what style added to the navbar then you can change style in this way. do you know how to get inspect element in browser? another case you cannot change bootstrap css..only thing is overide particular css.

Comment: I try, but when change height nothing changes.

Comment: please clear cache and checkit..use private window in firefox browser

Comment: I find how to change height. It need min-height value change to another, than add to navbar class height. And it's working. Only left that in smartphones be different height. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this css

```
.navbar {
    height: YOUR_SIZE !important;
}
```

Comment: No changes when I add this.

Comment: add !important before size

Comment: Check the inspector. Is the style not applied? Is it being overwritten? Saying "it doesn't work" just isn't good enough.